# Bluetooth, Sockets and Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was wondering if there is a way to handle bluetooth connections using Connectivity Manager and Network Interface instead of the dedicated Bluetooth api? My code needs to handle Bluetooth, WIFI and GPRS connection and was hoping all connections could be handled in the same way.

Comment: Any problem in computer science
can be solved by adding another level of indirection. (David Wheeler?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as `ConnectivityManager` supports [`TYPE_BLUETOOTH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_BLUETOOTH). All layers above should be able to handle this independently of the type of the connection.

Comment: I should have given a little more information. I was hoping that I could get an adapter IP address from Network Interface and use that address to listen for socket accepts. I was also hoping to use the ServerSocket class instead of the BluetoothServerSocket class. Possible?

Comment: Network connections via Bluetooth tethering can probably be handled the same as every other network connection and you can just ask for your IP. Everything else probably not. Without knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve, it's hard to answer this for you. You should improve your question with more detail.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I have an application that will both accept and connect sockets. The incoming requests and outgoing connections can be through either WIFI, Bluetooth or GPRS. I want to be able to control the incoming and outgoing connections through the desired adapter through the socket api. I am able to do this with wifi and gprs through the connectivity manager and network interface api. I wanted to write generic code for bluetooth but I can;t seem to connect two bluetooth devices.

Comment: After I found your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12717874/1467115) it is now more clear to me what you are trying to achieve. This is not possible however, as typical Bluetooth connections are not based on the IP protocol and don't work as typical network connections (unless you look at tethering, where you have an IP layer *on top* of the Bluetooth connection). You should probably open an [RFCOMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFCOMM) connection to exchange data using Bluetooth.